# Start new session in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a session that I turn into a variable `$userID`.

I now need to use the variable within a different controller. I have tried to start a new session after the session   `$this->session->sess_destroy();`.

Then on my second controller I have tried to get the session data but I am getting NULL.

**First controller**

```
public function index()
{

    if ($this->input->post('tid')) {

        $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $userID = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        $this->session->set_userdata($userID);

        $this->input->post('userid');
        $data['tid'] = $this->input->post('tid');
        $this->load->view('client/login', $data);


    } else {
        header("Location: " . base_url() . "index.php/select");
        die();
    }

}
```

**Second controller**

```
private function getResults()
{
    $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    $userID = $this->session->userdata('userid');

    var_dump($userID);
}
```

If I `vardump` the variable in my first controller after session destroy, the variable prints out. However it does not on the second.

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of header() die; why not use codeigniter redirect() from the url helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is your problem but I think there's a problem on this line:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($userID);
```

[`set_userdata` accepts two kinds of arguments (link to docs) :](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data)

1. a single argument as an associative array of keys and values or
2. a "key" first argument and a "value" second argument

So what you're probably looking to do is rather

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $userId);
```

or

```
$data = ['user_id' => $userId];
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

As you prefer. Also, as a side note, this kind of code gets repeated a few times :

```
$this->session->userdata('user_id');
$userID = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

The first call is useless and should be removed.

Comment: Glad I could help you!